# Strange behaviour when comparing two strings with ==

Tags: c#

I have observed a strange behaviour when comparing two strings with ==.
A little bit of context: The following code is from an application which should act as server and it should validate the thumbprint of the clientcertificate.

I have a client application with a certificate with the following thumbprint: "2074529C99D93D5955FEECA859AEAC6092741205". When I call the server this method returns Valid:

```
static CertificateValidationResult ValidateClientCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientcertificate)
{
    return clientcertificate.Thumbprint == "‎2074529C99D93D5955FEECA859AEAC6092741205"
                       ? CertificateValidationResult.Valid
                       : CertificateValidationResult.Rejected;
}
```

After I changed to a clientcertificate with the thumbprint "‎F9A021D2EFDCD3BD13671CE1D25CFE51BA5BA38E" and changed the server code the following method returns Rejected:

```
static CertificateValidationResult ValidateClientCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientcertificate)
{
    return clientcertificate.Thumbprint == "‎F9A021D2EFDCD3BD13671CE1D25CFE51BA5BA38E"
                       ? CertificateValidationResult.Valid
                       : CertificateValidationResult.Rejected;
}
```

In each case the strings are exactly the same, but only the first one returned Valid. Why is this happening?

Comment: Make sure you are executing the newly changed code. Build/consume the library which has method CertificateValidationResult.

Comment: Have you debugged this and checked the value of the Thumbprint and are 100% sure they are exactly the same?

Comment: Do not make assumptions about your values. Use the debugger....

Comment: Lowercase/uppercase issue perhaphs ? Try return string.Compare(clientcertificate.Thumbprint, 
  "your string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
  ? CertificateValidationResult.Valid : CertificateValidationResult.Rejected; instead.

Comment: I did a rebuild of the server and clientcode. And of course I used the debugger and can confirm that the values were the same.

Comment: Everything was in uppercase, this shouldn't be the problem. By the way: string.Equals worked as expected.

Comment: @Mystery - It would be worth updating your question to highlight that `String.Equals` works whereas `==` doesn't. This wasn't clear in your question until your latest comment. Also, did you copy/paste your thumbprint or type it manually. There have been instances where pasting also includes "duff" invisible characters that breaks `==` so try deleting and hand-typing. See if that fixes it.

Comment: the string in your method starts with a left to right mark, I don't know how you did to put it in there but just check the length of your string and find out that it is composed of 41 characters not 40...

Comment: @Belogix Thank you. I did copy/paste it, typing it manually fixed the issue. Can you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Mystery - Answer added and glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied / pasted the Thumbprint you may have accidentally copied a hidden character / symbol. Often these don't appear in the Visual Studio IDE even if you enable "Show Whitespace". This can cause all sorts of strange side-effects as you have witnessed.

The best approach is to manually type out the thumbprint into Visual Studio which will ensure no funny characters have slipped in. This can be a bit of a pain but the only way of guaranteeing you are actually comparing like for like.